# No puedo generar un return en python

Tags: python

La idea es que pueda llamar el valor regular hours, para usarlo mas adelante

```
def inical_information():
 salary = input("Enter Salary: ")
 salary = float(salary)
 regular_hours = salary / 235


print('Salary register is: ${:,.2f}'.format(salary))
print('regular hour value is: ${:,.2f}'.format(regular_hours))

return(salary,regular_hours)
```

inical_information()

Comment: Buen día, el problema es por el [`alcance`](https://apuntes.de/python/alcance-de-variables-en-python-global-y-local/#gsc.tab=0) de las variables.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a intentar resolverte la duda con el siguiente código:

```
def inical_information():
    salary = float(input("Enter Salary: "))  # Reducimos una línea de código
    regular_hours = salary / 235
    return [salary, regular_hours]

salary, regular_hours = inical_information()

print('Salary register is: ${:,.2f}'.format(salary))
print('regular hour value is: ${:,.2f}'.format(regular_hours))
```

Al definir una variable dentro de una función, esa variable solo será verdad dentro de ese proceso; al acabar la función esa variable ya no se puede volver a llamar. No obstante, si creas un return puedes obtener los valores devueltos de una función y convertir las variables locales en globales.